Permission Set Assignment for non-admin users in Test Class for CPQ objects
I have read a lot about my issue but can't seem to overcome it. I need to write what I thought was a simple test class for Salesforce CPQ quotes. I need to be able to run the test as users of two different profiles.
I insert my users, and then to avoid mixed DML, I need to assign permission sets inside the System.runAs(). However no matter what I try, the test fails with the error "Permission to update an SBQQ__Quote__c denied."
I have tried using the @future approach as well to avoid the mixed DML, but still isn't working.
What seems odd to me is that, a non-admin user typically wouldnt be able to create a permission set assignment, so maybe it is silently failing, however, the permission set assignments from what I have read, only apply within the runAs block for that user...So I can assign the permission sets running as admin, but then I can't pass those assignments to the other runAs blocks, and I don't see a workaround. I even tried 'nesting' the runAs statements with the admin user on top but no dice
public static void testValdiation(){
        Account account = TestData.buildAndInsertAccount('Test Acc');
        Opportunity oppty = TestData.buildAndInsertOpportunity(account.Id,'Test Oppty', 'Stage 1 - Qualification');
        SBQQ__Quote__c quote = TestData.buildAndInsertQuote(account.Id, oppty.Id, UserInfo.getUserId());
        Id aeProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Account Executive'].Id;
        Id salesOpsProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Sales Operations'].Id;
        User aeUser = TestData.createUser(aeProfileId);
        User salesOpsUser = TestData.createUser(salesOpsProfileId);
        insert new List<User>{aeUser, salesOpsUser};
      
        Test.startTest();

            System.runAs(salesOpsUser) {        
                PermissionSetLicense psl = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSetLicense WHERE DeveloperName = 'SalesforceCPQ_CPQStandardPerm'];
                PermissionSetLicenseAssign psaAe = new PermissionSetLicenseAssign(AssigneeId = aeUser.Id, PermissionSetLicenseId = psl.Id);
                PermissionSetLicenseAssign psaOps = new PermissionSetLicenseAssign(AssigneeId = salesOpsUser.Id, PermissionSetLicenseId = psl.Id);
    
                PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'Salesforce_CPQ_Li'];
                PermissionSetAssignment psAe = new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = aeUser.Id, PermissionSetId = ps.Id);
                PermissionSetAssignment psOps = new PermissionSetAssignment(AssigneeId = salesOpsUser.Id, PermissionSetId = ps.Id);
    
                insert new List<PermissionSetLicenseAssign>{psaOps, psaAe};
                insert new List<PermissionSetAssignment>{psOps, psAe};             
                quote.Sales_Support_Verified__c = true;
                Database.SaveResult result = Database.update(quote, true);
                Assert.areEqual(true, result.isSuccess(),'Quote should have saved');
            }
            
            System.runAs(aeUser) {
                quote.Sales_Support_Verified__c = false;
                Database.SaveResult result = Database.update(quote, false);
                Assert.areNotEqual(true, result.isSuccess(),'Quote should not have saved');
                
                for(Database.Error error: result.getErrors()) {
                    Assert.areEqual(Label.Sales_Support_Verified_Error, error.getMessage());
                }
            }
        Test.stopTest();
    }


why wouldn't you set up the PSAs by running as a System Administrator?; that's what I do for all my mocked PSAs
